# Back up Event Viewer folder using backup exec without installing the remote agent

Tags: backupexec, eventviewer

How to backup a shared folder without installing the remote agent?
I used and enabled the "Enable selection of user shares" but an error appears "Failed to connect to computer"!

I appreciate any other solutions to backup the event viewer folder using Backup Exec 2010 R3.

Thanks,
Khalid

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a BE Remote Agent license installed on the BE server? I believe that's a requirement for backing up user defined shares. In addition, you need to define your user defined selections and select those in your selection list, NOT the shares viewable from the server itself.